# Is this reasoning valid for showing that E is not closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$E = \{ n/(n+1)\mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

$E = \{1/2 , 2/3 , 3/4 , 4/5 , \ldots\}$

But $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n/(n+1) = 1 \notin E.$ Hence $E$ does not contain all its limit points so it is not closed.

Comment: You may want to include some parentheses.

Comment: @Michael Because it is a limit of a sequence?

Comment: @Michael I couldn’t bear it either so I added them

Comment: How is "closed" defined? (It'd be helpful to add this to the post - there's a number of equivalent definitions and different ones are used in different contexts, some of which allow this proof, some of which do not)

Comment: My guess is this is for a class, so you may need to show that the limit of a sequence is a limit point depending on the definitions you're using and what you've proven so far. Alternatively, writing the complement of $E$ as a union of open intervals will also get you there.